# MySql Multiple Tables query

Tags: mysql

I wonder if any can help me understand something I'm trying to solve.

I'm working on a wordpress site but this is more a sql question as I'm just querying to get some results within a template file.

I have a gallery of pictures which are advert boxes, and I need to pull these in relation to a supplied movie name, to do this Im using some custom fields on the ad pic called 'adlink' (link off ad) and ad

I'm using the nextgen gallery plugin and querying those tables, and I have three tables in total that contain the data I need to query.

ngg_pictures, nggcf_field_values & nggcf_fields.

the nggcf tables are custom fields tables,

I have got so far I can get what I need in two seperate queries, but I can't combine these into one query as it means querying the nggcf_field_values table twice, which I can't seem to sort.

I have hardcoded the search criteria in for the mo, but the 'close-encounters' bit would be a passed var, and the '156' would be the pid from the first query.

```
SELECT `eg_ngg_pictures`.`filename`, `eg_nggcf_field_values`.`fid`, `eg_nggcf_field_values`.`pid`
FROM eg_ngg_pictures, eg_nggcf_field_values
WHERE ((`eg_nggcf_field_values`.`field_value` LIKE 'close-encounters') AND (`eg_nggcf_field_values`.`pid` = eg_ngg_pictures.pid))



SELECT `eg_nggcf_field_values`.`field_value`
FROM eg_nggcf_field_values, eg_nggcf_fields
WHERE ((`eg_nggcf_fields`.`field_name` = 'adlink') AND (`eg_nggcf_fields`.`id` = eg_nggcf_field_values.fid) AND (`eg_nggcf_field_values`.`pid`  = '156'))
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, I can get the results with what I have, but I like to understand how to combine these two and write better SQl. Thanks MRO

Comment: Learn about left, inner and outer joins.  I believe it would do what your trying to do.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html is a link

Comment: thanks, looks really useful - I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the [Wordpress extension](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/nextgen-gallery-custom-fields/tags/0.1/ngg-custom-fields.php), I think the `eg_nggcf_fields` is the table that contains the name for a custom field.  The `eg_nggcf_field_values` table contains the values of that custom field per picture.

So if you're looking for two fields called `moviename` and `adlink`, you have to look up two rows in the `field_values` table.  You can join a table twice if you give it a different alias:

```
select  pic.filename
,       pic.pid
,       fv1.field_value as MovieName
,       fv2.field_value as Adlink
from    eg_ngg_pictures pic
inner join -- Find ID for the field called 'moviename'
        eg_nggcf_fields f1
on      f1.field_name = 'moviename'
inner join -- Find value for field moviename for this picture
        eg_nggcf_field_values as fv1
on      fv1.pid = pic.pid
        and fv1.fid = f1.fid
inner join -- Find ID for the field called 'adlink'
        eg_nggcf_fields f2
on      f2.field_name = 'adlink'
inner join -- Find value for field adlink for this picture
        eg_nggcf_field_values as fv2
on      fv2.pid = pic.pid
        and fv2.fid = f2.fid
where   fv1.field_value like 'close-encounters'
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd recommend sticking to modern ANSI syntax for JOINing tables, which means using the JOIN clause.

Instead of using:

```
FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.pid
```

use:

```
FROM Table 1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

For simplicity's sake, I'd also recommend you to alias tables, as that tends to make the code more readable. Instead of having to write out `egg_ngg_pictures` every time, you can simply refer to the alias you assign it instead.

Lastly, when you use a `LIKE` operator, you usually add a wild-card character  (typically `%`. I.e. `LIKE '%123'` or `LIKE '123%'`). You seem to look only for complete matches, which means you can just stick to using `=`, as that should give you slightly better performance.

Now to rewrite your query, I'd use something like the following:

```
SELECT 
    pic.filename
    , fieldval.fid
    , fieldval.pid
    , fieldval.field_value
FROM 
    eg_ngg_pictures pic
        JOIN eg_nggcf_field_values fieldval ON fieldval.pid = pic.pid
        JOIN eg_nggcf_fields fields ON fields.id = fieldval.fid
WHERE 
    ((fieldval.field_value = 'close-encounters') 
    AND fields.field_name = 'ad_link'
```

Note that I am not able to test the query, as I do not have your schema. But by incorporating the two queries into a single query, the join on the field_Values.PID retreieved with the 'close_encounters' value should already exist.

If the query does not work, feel free to create a SQL fiddle with the relevant tables and some data, and I'll try and get it to work with that.

Comment: Hi Thanks very much - that's really usefull, I have been playing around with sql fiddle (thanks for the tip) as yet it's not playing, here's what I have so far http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8138a1/3